# SQL - How to aggregate and limit results to one row per ID based on the aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to put together a SQL query for a couple hours and can't seem to get it right.  Consider the following example tables `Products` and `ProductCategories`:

```
Products
--------
ProductId   ProductName
---------   -----------
1         | Achilles
2         | Hermes
3         | Apollo
4         | Zeus
5         | Poseidon
6         | Eros

ProductCategories
-----------------
ProductId   Category
---------   --------
1         | Wars
1         | Wars|Trojan
1         | Wars|Trojans|Mortals
1         | Toys|Games
2         | Travel
2         | Travel|Trade
2         | Communication|Language|Writing
5         | Oceanware
6         | Love
6         | Love|Candy
6         | Love|Valentines
3         | Sunshine
4         | Lightning
```

The goal would be to select the product ID, product name and one of the categories associated with the product such that each product ID/name appears once in the results and the category that is selected is the one with the most pipe characters in it.  In the case that 2 (or more) categories for a product are tied for the most pipes, then randomly picking either of them will work.

In other words, the query should result in this dataset:

```
ProductId   ProductName     Category
---------   -----------     --------
1         | Achilles      | Wars|Trojans|Mortals
2         | Hermes        | Communication|Language|Writing
3         | Apollo        | Sunshine
4         | Zeus          | Lightning
5         | Poseidon      | Oceanware
6         | Eros          | Love|Valentines
```

(Note, the category returned for Eros could also be Love|Candy, either is acceptable)

As of now, I have this SQL, which obviously doesn't work because it returns a row for each Product/Category combination, not just the category with the most pipes:

```
SELECT
    ProductId,
    ProductName,
    Category,
    MAX(PipeCount)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProductId AS ProductId,
        p.ProductName AS ProductName,
        c.Category AS Category,
        LEN(c.CategoryName) - LEN(REPLACE(c.CategoryName, '|', '')) AS PipeCount
    FROM
        Products p
        INNER JOIN ProductCategories c
        ON p.ProductId = c.ProductId
) Subquery
GROUP BY ProductId, ProductName, Category, PipeCount
```

I can't seem to get my query any closer than this, however.  I was to return only the row for each product where the PipeCount is the max PipeCount for any row for the product.  Any help would be appreciated.  Please note this is not my actual data; it's much more complicated than this, but this example should suffice.  I am working on SQL Server 2012, but hopefully a good answer would be compatible with virtually any version of SQL.

Comment: The answer with `ROW_NUMBER()` will provide correct results, but I have two notes. 1) I'd store the data differently. Instead of putting several elements in a `|-delimited` list I'd put each element in its own row in a separate table (normalize the structure). The more data you have, the more important it becomes. 2) The formula for calculating number of `|` may produce incorrect result. For this: `A|B |` it will return 3 instead of 2. There is a space before the last `|`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - I couldn't agree more about normalizing, but I didn't create the tables.  The string format is something baked into the integration with a third party service.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - As for the LEN(REPLACE()) issue, I am perplexed.  Why would it get rid of the space if I'm only asking it to replace pipes?  In any case, this won't affect my situation as every single category follows the format x|y|z.  Pipes and spaces never occur at the end of the strings.

Comment: `LEN` function ignores trailing spaces. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks." Comparison (=) operator also ignores trailing spaces. Just something that is worth knowing for T-SQL. `DATALENGTH` doesn't, but it counts bytes, not characters.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Wow.  This seems like a terrible idea unless there's a very good reason for it.  Do you know of any reason they chose to implement it this way?

Comment: `char(N)` is right-padded with spaces (to make N characters). These trailing spaces are ignored by `LEN` and comparison. `varchar(N)` is not right-padded with spaces, but `LEN` and comparison still ignores trailing spaces. `DECLARE @c char(5) = 'A';` `DECLARE @vc varchar(5) = 'A';` `@c` has value `A` with 4 spaces after it. `@vc` has value `A` without spaces. `LEN(@c)=1` `LEN(@vc)=1` `IF @c = @vc` returns true. `DECLARE @c2 char(50) = 'A';` `@c2` has value `A` with 49 spaces after it. `IF @c = @c2` returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem using various subqueries.  One caveat is that it depends on the `ProductCategories` table in my example having a unique column that I did not explicitly specify.  In my real data, this column exists already, but facing a similar problem, one could add such a column to make this solution work.  Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT
    Sub1.ProductId,
    Sub3.Category
FROM
(
    SELECT
        o.ProductId AS ProductId,
        MAX(LEN(REPLACE(c.Category, '|', '||')) - LEN(c.Category)) AS MaxPipeCount
    FROM
        Products o
        INNER JOIN ProductCategories c
            ON o.ProductId = c.ProductId
    GROUP BY o.ProductID
) Sub1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        o.ProductId AS ProductId,
        LEN(REPLACE(c.Category, '|', '||')) - LEN(c.Category) AS PipeCount,
        MAX(c.UniqueId) AS MaxUniqueId
    FROM
        Products o
        INNER JOIN ProductCategories c
            ON o.ProductId = c.ProductId
    GROUP BY o.ProductID, LEN(REPLACE(c.Category, '|', '||')) - LEN(c.Category)
) Sub2
    ON Sub1.MaxPipeCount = Sub2.PipeCount
    AND Sub1.ProductId = Sub2.ProductId
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        o.ProductId,
        c.Category,
        LEN(REPLACE(c.Category, '|', '||')) - LEN(c.Category) AS PipeCount,
        c.UniqueId
    FROM 
        Products o
        INNER JOIN ProductCategories c
            ON o.ProductId = c.ProductId
) Sub3
    ON Sub1.MaxPipeCount = Sub3.PipeCount
    AND Sub2.MaxUniqueId = Sub3.UniqueId
    AND Sub1.ProductId = Sub3.ProductId
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the `ProductId` with the most number of `CategoryName`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8375f/1/0)

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    pc.CategoryName
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT 
        *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY LEN(CategoryName) - LEN(REPLACE(CategoryName, '|', '')) DESC)
    FROM ProductCategories
) pc
    ON pc.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: The formula for calculating number of `|` may produce incorrect result. For this: `A|B |` it will return 3 instead of 2. There is a space before the last `|` in my example. It looks like changing the formula to this fixes it: `LEN(REPLACE(CategoryName, '|', '__')) - LEN(CategoryName)`. You can replace `|` with a pair of any non-space symbols, not just `__` here.

Comment: I guess first thing the OP should do is to prevent that form of data to be inserted. However, the best thing to do here is to normalize the data such that each `Product`-`Category` combination is a separate row on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Here solution using `ROW_NUMBER`

```
--CTE as data sample for two tables
;
WITH    Products
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     ( VALUES ( 1, 'Achilles'), ( 2, 'Hermes'),
                        ( 3, 'Apollo'), ( 4, 'Zeus'), ( 5, 'Poseidon'),
                        ( 6, 'Eros') ) AS t ( ProductId, ProductName )
             ),
        ProductCategories
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     ( VALUES ( 1    , 'Wars'), ( 1  , 'Wars|Trojan'),
                        ( 1 , 'Wars|Trojans|Mortals'), ( 1  , 'Toys|Games'),
                        ( 2 , 'Travel'), ( 2    , 'Travel|Trade'),
                        ( 2 , 'Communication|Language|Writing'),
                        ( 5 , 'Oceanware'), ( 6 , 'Love'),
                        ( 6 , 'Love|Candy'), ( 6    , 'Love|Valentines'),
                        ( 3 , 'Sunshine'), ( 4  , 'Lightning') ) AS T ( ProductId, CategoryName )
             )

--Final Query

    SELECT  T.ProductId ,
            T.ProductName ,
            T.CategoryName
    FROM    ( SELECT    P.ProductID ,
                        P.ProductName ,
                        C.CategoryName ,
                        LEN(C.CategoryName) - LEN(REPLACE(C.CategoryName, '|', '')) AS Pipes ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY P.ProductID ORDER BY LEN(C.CategoryName)
                                            - LEN(REPLACE(C.CategoryName, '|',
                                                          '')) DESC, LEN(C.CategoryName) DESC ) AS RN
              FROM      Products AS P
                        JOIN ProductCategories AS C ON P.ProductId = C.ProductId
            ) AS T
    WHERE   T.RN = 1
```